# "Extra argument 'foo' in call" OR "'[NSObject : AnyObject]!' is not a subtype of 'Dictionary<Key, Value>'"

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdictionary

I've read all the "extra argument in call" posts I can find, but am still banging my head against this one. I have a method that looks like this:

```
// Objective-C
+ (void)get:(NSString *)url params:(NSDictionary *)params completion:(NetworkCompletion)completion

// Swift autocomplete
GenericWebService.get(url: String!, params: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, completion: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void)!)
```

My first attempt to use this method in Swift looks like this...

```
GenericWebService.get("", params: ["foo":"bar"], completion: {
    (responseDictionary: Dictionary, connectionError: NSError) -> Void in
        // foo
    })
```

...and yielded the error `Extra argument 'params' in call`

So I tried to provide a better type match for params (`[NSObject:AnyObject]`)...

```
let params: [NSObject:AnyObject] = ["foo":"bar"]
GenericWebService.getURL("", params: params, completion: {
    (responseDictionary: Dictionary, connectionError: NSError) -> Void in
        // foo
    })
```

...which yields `'[NSObject : AnyObject]!' is not a subtype of 'Dictionary<Key, Value>'`

What boneheaded mistake am I making? :)

Comment: Even in Swift begining the name of a method with "get" is still a bad coding convention. And `get` what, the name does not give a clus about what is does. Also naming a string parameter "url" is confusing at best, what would you name a URL parameter?

Comment: I agree, @Zaph. The method in question came from existing code...one thing at a time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the closure argument.  If you make the parameters match exactly, it works:

```
GenericWebService.get("", params: ["foo":"bar"]) {
    (responseDictionary: [NSObject:AnyObject]!, connectionError: NSError!) -> Void in
    // foo
}
```

But rather than explicitly type them, it may be easier just to leave Swift to do it for you:

```
GenericWebService.get("", params: ["foo":"bar"]) {
    responseDictionary, connectionError in
    // foo
}
```

Comment: Coding is not about easier to write, it is about clarity in reading/understanding. Omitting the type information just adda confusion, consider that the OP named a URL parameter `string`.

Comment: I don’t disagree with you, however in many situations the types are clutter and make it harder to read including (IMO) this case.  The #1 thing to fix here really is eliminating all the AnyObjects and implicit optionals...

Answer (score 1):

I believe your second error is complaining about the type of your completion block, not the type of the `params` parameter. This works for me:

```
GenericWebService.get("", params: ["foo": "bar"], completion: {
    (a: [NSObject: AnyObject]!, b: NSError!) in
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In a playground, I found that this syntax also compiles correctly:

```
GenericWebService.get("", params: ["foo" : "bar"], completion: {
        (responseDictionary _: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, connectionError _: NSError!) -> Void in
    })
```